# Ajax Request to Django Application

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I am trying to submit a form by using jquery post method. Every time the form is submitted, the request parameters (request.POST) is empty. I am not sure why the ajax request is failing to send the parameters. The js code:

```
<script>
$('#myform').on('submit', function(e){
  let username = $("#username").val();
  let password = $("#password").val();
  let url = $('#myform').attr('action');
  $.post(url, {
    username:username,
    password:password
  }, function(d){
    alert('success');
  });
});
$('#login').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#myform').submit();
});
```

What am I doing wrong in this step? If needed, I can most the html form and, the view function dealing with the form's action url.

Comment: Do you have csrf in the request? python - Django CSRF check failing with an Ajax POST request - Stack ...

Comment: yeah, post the html and view.

Comment: Do you need to use the `post` method? you can use `$.ajax()` and pass CSRF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following, and check the Django server log to check if has received a request, and what is the request status code.

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data: {
                      username:username,
                      password:password,
                      csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                    },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.message);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data.message);
        }
    },
```

Comment: This seemed to have worked. Thanks. Btw, I removed the csrf middleware from django settings (just to get going for now). However, looking at the code you presented, I was wondering about how to obtain a csrf token? Since, I will be using it anyways when the code goes live, I would be grateful if you explain about the csrf_token and, what values needs to used for it.

Comment: Django, by default, provides a Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) token to protect your views. You do not have to worry about how to create it or what its value, Django will take care of it. You will only need to pass the token when your submitting a form, by using `{{ csrf_token }}` to get the value. Cross Site Request Forgeries are security attacks to a website. Django tries to protect you from these attacks by requiring the all POST request to include the token. Read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/) for more information on CSRF.

Answer (score 1):

Try what @Algorithmatic is suggesting, I think it will work. Also visit those tuts below for better understanding AJAx requests. It was a pain for me too..

https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

Comment: Thanks @danae for the suggestions. Looking into these posts right away